# Configure email notification triggers on WooCommerce Advanced Notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am using WooCommerce Advanced Notifications to send emails and as of v1.2.10 a filter has been added so you can change the trigger but I cannot get it to work.

**The filter hook looks like this:**

```
    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_advanced_notifications_multiple_statuses_trigger', true ) ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'new_order' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed', array( $this, 'new_order' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold', array( $this, 'new_order' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing', array( $this, 'new_order' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed', array( $this, 'new_order' ) );
    } else {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array( $this, 'new_order' ) );
    }
```

**What I would like to achieve**

I'd like to be able to add my own trigger (e.g. processing_to_completed) and remove other triggers (e.g. pending_to_on-hold).

**Where I've got to**

I used this (http://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/26-wordpress-actions-filters-and-hooks-a-guide-for-non-developers) guide to understand more about filters and I've worked out that I can change which part of the if statement is used by adding this code to my functions.php

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_advanced_notifications_multiple_statuses_trigger', false );
```

But I can't see how to add new triggers. I cannot see how to pass a variable back into the filter.

I'd appreciate a point in the right direction. Thanks, Laura.

Comment: What are you aiming for? Do you want to remove the multiple status triggers? Or do you want to add an additional one?

Comment: Hi Helga. I'd like to be able to add my own trigger (e.g. processing_to_completed) and remove other triggers (e.g. pending_to_on-hold). I've edited question to clarify.

Comment: Well if you `add_filter( 'woocommerce_advanced_notifications_multiple_statuses_trigger', '__return_false' );` that should disable the multiple status triggers and only leave you with the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` trigger.

Comment: But you still want to fire the plugin's `new_order` method on that action? Can you show more of this class? How does one instantiate the class?

Comment: Thanks Helga I'll check your suggestion and provide more details.

Comment: Helga I've tried that code but it doesn't seem to work. I've also hooked a function that returns 'false' to the filter and that doesn't work either. I've wrapped the filter in a function and hooked it to init and that doesn't help! That filter doesn't seem to work! I've sorta given up and just edited the plugin. Eww. Hacky!

Comment: Laura, next question. Where you are calling `add_filter()`? Your comment that the filter isn't working makes me think maybe you are trying to access it after it has already fired. Can you try to do it from a custom plugin?

Comment: I've tried it in a custom plugin and in functions.php. I'll try working out if the filter is being registered using this guidance: http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/check-if-a-hook-is-being-filtered-using-has_filter/ and come back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use **WooCommerce Advanced Notifications** plugin as I can do this kind of things my self with custom code. So here is the way to do it (very simply):

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_completed', 'order_processing_to_completed_new_order_notification', 10, 2 );
 function order_processing_to_completed_new_order_notification( $order_id, $order ){
     $wc_email = new WC_Email_New_Order($order_id);
     $wc_email->trigger( $order_id, $order );
 }
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: Could you name that function so it isn't anonymous?

Comment: @helgatheviking I am too Mexican today, too much tequila… (joking). I will do it now (Is it really important if it's on the active theme function.php file?) …

Comment: I could go for some tequila. Really heartbreaking to read what happened in Mexico. You are right that if it's in the theme it's probably ok, but I think it's more readable with a name. Plus, this is functionality and should go into a plugin anyway.

Comment: @helgatheviking We have done the change nearly at the same time… As you where faster, the last one is mine :)

Comment: Thanks Loic. Your solution is neat, but not quite what I am looking for. The Woo Adv Notification plugin allows you to attribute different 'suppliers' to each product and notify them when a purchase of that product is made and I want to build on this functionality. I'll post if I come up with something.

Comment: @LauraTheExplorer I can do that in my function, but I not it with your plugin as I don't have it and I can't make any test. This is funny, because the 3 of us have similar SO names here :)